# How to find the given position for each row of data frame 1, in the data frame2 to extract the information from data frame 2

Tags: r

Hi I have a complex problem, I couldn't figure how to solve.

I have two data frame, and I want to conditionally match one column of df1 to df2.

```
Df1:
gene int start_pos  end_pos  tag
A    1   233        422      a1
A    2   622        766      a2
A    3   1021       1211     ab
A    4   1400       1500     b1
A    4   2000       2200     b2
B    1   122        233      a1
B    2   332        665      a2
C    1   199        433      a1
C    2   776        899      a2

df2:
Gene  type   pos  
A     shrt   680
A     long   1420
B     shrt   350
C     long   790
```

I want to match these two table, based on 'pos' information.

I want to: Check pos (position) in df2 for each gene, and find it's location in df1. For example first row in df 2 A-680, I want to find gene A in df1, then search position 680, and find which 'tag' corresponds to this position.

So in the end I want to add a column to df2, based on tag information from df1, like this:

```
df2:
Gene  type   pos   tag 
A     shrt   680   a2
A     long   1420  b1
B     shrt   350   a2
C     long   790   a2
```

I couldn't find any solution to do this. Merge doesn't work because I can't make unique identifier. I couldn't find a solution with match function either.

Note: df1 is basically a reference data. All the positions in df two is in between a start and stop in df1. I want to find tag information for each position in df1.

I am stuck. Any help would be great.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Problem that you are facing with joining was that the column name is not the same (gene vs Gene).

Here is the code that you are looking for:

```
library(dplyr)
Df1 <- data.frame(gene = c("A", "A","A","A","A","B","B","C","C") ,
              int = c(1,2,3,4,4,1,2,1,2),
              start_pos = c(233,622,1021,1400,2000,122,332,199,776), 
              end_pos = c(422,766,1211,1500,2200,233,665,433,899),
              tag = c("a1", "a2","ab","b1","b2" , "a1","a2","a1","a2") )


df2 <- data.frame(Gene = c("A","A","B","C"), 
              type = c("shrt", "long", "shrt", "long"),
              pos = c(680,1420,350,790))


colnames(Df1)[1] <- "Gene"       ## matching the column name

Merge_data <- inner_join(df2,Df1)
filter_data <- filter(Merge_data, pos > start_pos & pos < end_pos)

Result <- select(filter_data, c(Gene,type,pos,tag))
```

The result is as follows

```
   Gene type  pos tag
1    A shrt  680  a2
2    A long 1420  b1
3    B shrt  350  a2
4    C long  790  a2
```

Comment: Thank you!!! this solved my issue. I used this solution with two 'list' instead of 'dataframe' and it worked (list because, I import two csv file for df1 and df2).

Comment: Instead of changing the name of the column, you can use by.x & by.y, which tells R to use these two columns to match

Answer (score 0):

Another much sloppier way to do this is to create a `list()` of data.frames based on the ranges for each gene position (variable `df2$pos` here, assumably).

This can be done with a `for loop` and subsetting the data using `which()`

First set up your new variable in `df2` and create two working lists, named `list1` and `list2`:

```
df2$tag <- NA
list1 <- list()
list2 <- list()
```

Now for the `for loop`:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df2)){
  # Use list1 to create a subset matching the genes
  list1[[i]] <- na.omit(df1[which(df2$Gene[i] == df1$gene),])
  # Use list2 to create a subset where df2$pos is greater than or equal to df1$start_pos
  list2[[i]] <- na.omit(list1[[i]][which(df2$pos[i] >= list1[[i]]$start_pos),])
  # Finally assign the 'tag' for df2$pos is less than o equal to df1$end_pos
  df2$tag[i] <- as.character(list2[[i]][which(df2$pos[i] <= list2[[i]]$end_pos),"tag"])
}
```

And we are left with:

```
  Gene type  pos tag
1    A shrt  680  a2
2    A long 1420  b1
3    B shrt  350  a2
4    C long  790  a2
```

Just giving you another option!